# Xamarin Forms Listview will not display on my iPone. However, it does on the simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-4.0

I have tried everything I could think of and everything I found on the web and have not had any luck, still a blank page.

here is my xaml file;

```
<ListView x:Name="AutoView" ItemsSource="{Binding AutoData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SeparatorVisibility="None"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="Purple">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Year}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <Switch x:Name="{Binding Id}" IsToggled="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Toggled="Handle_Toggled" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

My code in my view model looks like this, I have changed it multiple times but this is where it is at now.

```
    public ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch> MyList = new ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch>();
    public ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch> AutoData = new ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch>(); //{ get { return MyList; } }
    private IPopupNavigation _popup { get; set; }
    private PopupPage _modalPage;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public UpdateCarsViewModel()
    {
        //Analytics.TrackEvent("Top of Constructor in UpdateCarsViewModel");
        GetDisplayData();
        Sort.SortOrder(MyList, i => i.Year, false);

        _popup = PopupNavigation.Instance;
        _modalPage = new PopupPage();
    }

    public void GetDisplayData()
    {
        MileageItemRepository repository = new MileageItemRepository();
        var response = repository.GetAuto2();

        //MyList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            Analytics.TrackEvent("Car Data GetDisplayData: carId " + item.Id + " Name = " + item.CarDesc + " Year = " + item.CarYear);
            
            AutoData.Add(new AutoWithSwitch
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Year = item.CarYear,
                Name = item.CarDesc,
                IsChecked = item.IsDefault
            });
            
            Analytics.TrackEvent("In GetDisplayData in UpdateCarsViewModel CarYear = " + item.CarYear);
        }
        //AutoData = MyList;
    }
```

As you can see I have logging in there and I can see the car information being retrieved from the DB table, it just will not display.

Comment: `AutoData` is not a property.  You can only bind to public properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your code snippets, **ListView** controls is binding to `AutoData` of type ObservableCollection and the data in side of list view will be binding to the properties of the class AutoWithSwitch to the four properties:
`Id`,`Year`,`Name` and `IsChecked`.
So you should claim and use the AutoData with set and get property like below:

```
public class UpdateCarsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch> mylist;
    public ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch> AutoData
    {
        get { return mylist; }
        set { mylist = value; }
    }
    public UpdateCarsViewModel()
    {
        GetDisplayData();
    }

    public void GetDisplayData()
    {
        //get data logic 
        AutoData = new ObservableCollection<AutoWithSwitch>()
        {
            new AutoWithSwitch()
            {
                Id = "1",
                Year = "2022",
                Name = "Steve_Jobs",
                IsChecked = false
            }
        };
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**:Make sure you can successfully retrieve data from below,

```
MileageItemRepository repository = new MileageItemRepository();
var response = repository.GetAuto2();
```

Comment: Yes, this was helpful. I just modified what was above a little in order to process more than one item at a time and it worked perfectly. I did it on my other pages that were not showing up and they are displaying fine now as well. Thank you so very much! I had spent hours trying to solve this so you help was GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful and aswered my question. Hope this is what you meant by answering that it was helpful.